# Why can't I change this global variable from function? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scopes

Simple countdown project.

Desired outcome:

1. global variable determines default time.
2. then slider value overrides that variable.

**PROBLEM: slider value changes locally but global value stays the same.**

I've watched tutorials all day on variable scopes and still don't see what's wrong because:

- Global is declared with "var" outside function: `var initialMinutes = 5`
- attempt to update value inside function looks like this:

```
const change = slider.addEventListener('change', setMins)

function setMins() {
    initialMinutes = slider.value
}
```

I have also tried with `window.variable` here and there to no avail.
I hope someone can help. This is becoming difficult to scope with.

```
const countdown = document.getElementById('countdown')
const slider = document.getElementById('slider')
const startBtn = document.getElementById('btn-startStop')
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('btn-reset')


// Event Listeners
const change = slider.addEventListener('change', setMins)
const start = startBtn.addEventListener('click', startStop)
const reset = resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetApp)

// Time
var initialMinutes = 15
countdown.innerHTML = initialMinutes+':00'
const initialDuration = initialMinutes * 60
let time = initialMinutes * 60

let interval = null
let status = 'stopped'

function updateCountdown() {

  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
  let seconds = time % 60
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+ seconds : seconds

  if( time < 1) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    startBtn.innerHTML = 'START'
    status = 'stopped'
    countdown.innerHTML = `00:00`
  } else {
    countdown.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`
    time--;
  }
}

function startStop() {
  if(status === 'stopped') {   
    interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 50)
    startBtn.innerHTML = 'STOP'
    status = 'running'
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval)
    startBtn.innerHTML = 'START'
    status = 'stopped'
  }
}

function setMins() {
    initialMinutes = slider.value
    countdown.innerHTML = slider.value+':00'
}
function resetApp() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '00:00'
  startBtn.innerHTML = 'START'
  status = 'stopped'
}
```

Codepen link included for clarity:
https://codepen.io/donseverino/pen/YzWBJYV

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I'm new here. I attached the complete code via CodePen link. Is that enough?

Comment: There's too much code there, it's hard to see the specific problem. Can't you narrow it down? And you don't need to use codepen, you can put the code here.

Comment: You don't update the countdown timer with the new value of `initialMinutes` after you change it.

Comment: How? I can change the innerHTML of the element but don't understand how to update the variable value.

Comment: You're updating the variable value correctly. You're just not doing anything with it after you update it.

Comment: Could you please explain how to pass the new value to the updateCountdown() function then?

Comment: `updateCountdown()` uses `time`, not `initialMinutes`. That's the variable you need to update.

Comment: Finally understood! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! It was not a problem of scope but of variable assignment.
`updateCountdown()` uses `time` and `time = initialMinutes * 60`

I thought changing `initialMinutes` would automatically change its value inside `time` but it doesn't.

Reassigning `time` inside the function solves it.

```
function setMins() {   
    initialMinutes = slider.value
    time = initialMinutes * 60
}
```

Comment: That's not how variable assignments work in most programming languages. Assigning a variable just copies the value, it doesn't make it a synonym for the expression.